# UI Bootstrap Datepicker dynamic DatepickerMode

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, uidatepicker

I have created a directive and template for the UI bootstrap date picker as well as templates for the monthly and yearly date picker modes currently my template looks like this 
[image]

I would like to update the datepickers DatepickerMode based on clicking the Monthly or Yearly buttons as some instances would require only a year value regardless of month, I've tried adding some functions in the directive to update the DatePickerMode but the templates ( Monthly and Yearly)  seem to use a different scope

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a decorator to add the additinal functionality

```
(function () {
var uibModel = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.datepicker');
uibModel.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('uibMonthpickerDirective', function ($delegate) {
        var directive = $delegate[0],
            link = directive.link;

        var controllerName = directive.controller;

        directive.compile = function () {
            return function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
                link.apply(this, arguments);
                scope.changeMode = function() {
                    scope.$parent.minMode = 'year';
                    scope.$parent.datepickerMode = 'year';
                    scope.$parent.datepickerOptions.datepickerMode = 'year';
                    scope.$parent.datepickerOptions.minMode = 'year';
                    scope.$parent.datepickerOptions.maxMode = 'year';

                };
            };
        };
        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

})();